# Android: Convert ProfilePictureView to Bitmap fail Facebook SDK 4.1

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap

I am trying to retrieve the Facebook Image from profilepictureview and convert it to bitmap but it gives me a blank profile pic. My main goal is to convert the image view to CircularImageView.

https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

The code is set in the onCreate method:

```
 profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.image_mainlobby);
 profilePictureView.setProfileId(userid);
 profilePictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.LARGE);

 ImageView fbImage = ( ( ImageView)profilePictureView.getChildAt( 0));
 Bitmap    bitmap  = ( ( BitmapDrawable) fbImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

 ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fb_profile);
 im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

1)onCreate method:

```
new DownloadImageTask((CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.fb_cir))
   .execute("https://graph.facebook.com/"+userid+"/picture?type=large");
```

2) create a new class

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
```

ImageView bmImage;

```
   public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
   this.bmImage = bmImage;
   }

   protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
       String urldisplay = urls[0];
       Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
       try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
       } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
       } 
         return mIcon11;
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
  }
```